# use-package arguments without use-package

Tags: init-file, use-package

The guide I'm following for `lsp-emacs` wants me to set these options:

```lisp
;; Enable scala-mode and sbt-mode
(use-package scala-mode
  :mode "\\.s\\(cala\\|bt\\)$")

(use-package sbt-mode
  :commands sbt-start sbt-command
  :config
  ;; WORKAROUND: https://github.com/ensime/emacs-sbt-mode/issues/31
  ;; allows using SPACE when in the minibuffer
  (substitute-key-definition
   'minibuffer-complete-word
   'self-insert-command
   minibuffer-local-completion-map))
```

but MELPA (and most likely mirrors of MELPA) are blocked on my school's internet, so I've been trying to use `load-file` with Git Submodules:

```lisp
;; Enable scala-mode and sbt-mode
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/scala-mode/scala-mode.el"
  :mode "\\.s\\(cala\\|bt\\)$")

(load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/sbt-mode/sbt-mode.el"
  :commands sbt-start sbt-command
  :config
  ;; WORKAROUND: https://github.com/ensime/emacs-sbt-mode/issues/31
  ;; allows using SPACE when in the minibuffer
  (substitute-key-definition
   'minibuffer-complete-word
   'self-insert-command
   minibuffer-local-completion-map))
```

However, the `:colon` commands aren't allowed as options on `load-file`. How can I get these options to work?

Comment: The [`use-package` documentation](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) is rather complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: install the package `use-package`, like you did with `sbt-mode` and `scala-mode` and be happy. ;)

You can not simply replace `use-package` with `load-file`. This are 2 completely different constructs. `use-package` is a macro, which changes the syntax of elisp, hence it can work with keywords like `:mode`, `:config` and so on. `load-file` is a simple function and has not the ability to change elisp's syntax.

`use-package`, when avaluated is expanded and its block is replaced by various lisp constructs.

`:mode` expands to stuff like:

```
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.s\\(cala\\|bt\\)$" . scala-mode)))
```

`:config` expands to stuff like:

```
    (eval-after-load 'sbt-mode
           (progn
           ....
         ))
```

`:commands` is replaced with stuff like:

```
      (autoload #'sbt-start "sbt-mode" nil t))
```

Your expanded use-package contructs look like this:

```
(progn
  (defvar use-package--warning81
    #'(lambda
    (keyword err)
    (let
        ((msg
          (format "%s/%s: %s" 'scala-mode keyword
              (error-message-string err))))
      (display-warning 'use-package msg :error))))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (progn
    (unless
        (fboundp 'scala-mode)
      (autoload #'scala-mode "scala-mode" nil t))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.s\\(cala\\|bt\\)$" . scala-mode)))
    (error
     (funcall use-package--warning81 :catch err))))

(progn
  (defvar use-package--warning82
    #'(lambda
    (keyword err)
    (let
        ((msg
          (format "%s/%s: %s" 'sbt-mode keyword
              (error-message-string err))))
      (display-warning 'use-package msg :error))))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (progn
    (unless
        (fboundp 'sbt-start)
      (autoload #'sbt-start "sbt-mode" nil t))
    (unless
        (fboundp 'sbt-command)
      (autoload #'sbt-command "sbt-mode" nil t))
    (eval-after-load 'sbt-mode
      '(condition-case-unless-debug err
           (progn
         (substitute-key-definition 'minibuffer-complete-word 'self-insert-command minibuffer-local-completion-map)
         t)
         (error
          (funcall use-package--warning82 :config err)))))
    (error
     (funcall use-package--warning82 :catch err))))
```

But you do not really need this, because it is used only to `defer` loading of a package.

You could just `require` the packages and set their options either with `customize` or `setq`.

Comment: So, once I add `use-package` as a git submodule like I did with the others, how do I load the other git submodules?

Comment: Ah, `use-package` just finds them if I disable `ensure` mode.